Why isn't Listable listed as an attribute of functions such as QuantityMagnitude and UnitConvert?
When I examine the attributes of the function Plus, Listable is one of the attributes listed:
Attributes[Plus]
(* {Flat, Listable, NumericFunction, OneIdentity, Orderless, Protected} *)

Indeed, Plus is a listable function, as seen in this example:
(* Applying the function to a list gives the same result as
   mapping the function across the list. *)
Plus[{1, 2, 3}, 10]
Map[Plus[#, 10] &, {1, 2, 3}]
(* {11, 12, 13} *)
(* {11, 12, 13} *)

The functions QuantityMagnitude and UnitConvert seem to be listable functions, as shown in these examples:
myQuantityList = {Quantity[14.1, "Micromolar"], 
   Quantity[15.2, "Micromolar"], Quantity[16.3, "Micromolar"]};

QuantityMagnitude[myQuantityList] // AbsoluteTiming
Map[QuantityMagnitude, myQuantityList] // AbsoluteTiming

UnitConvert[myQuantityList, "Millimolar"] // AbsoluteTiming
Map[UnitConvert[#, "Millimolar"] &, myQuantityList] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.0000308, {14.1, 15.2, 16.3}} *)
(* {0.0000121, {14.1, 15.2, 16.3}} *)
(* {0.000096, {0.0141 mM, 0.0152 mM, 0.0163 mM}} *)
(* {0.0000325, {0.0141 mM, 0.0152 mM, 0.0163 mM}} *)

But when I apply Attributes to QuantityMagnitude and UnitConvert, Listable isn't listed:
Attributes[QuantityMagnitude]
Attributes[UnitConvert]
(* {Protected, ReadProtected} *)
(* {Protected} *)

Why isn't Listable listed as an attribute of QuantityMagnitude and UnitConvert? Aren't these functions in fact listable functions?

listable is more like threadable. you aren’t threading over anything in your examples.

i guess your unitconvert example is sort of threading. does it also work if the units are in a list? (i’m not able to test it myself at the moment)

After some tests, it seems that QuantityMagnitude and UnitConvert both do thread over their arguments, so they behave as if they are Listable.

On a related note, the behavior of Listable can be achieved by means other than assigning it as an attribute, simply by making appropriate definitions.

From the docs, QuantityMagnitude is distributed over both arguments. QuantityMagnitude[{Quantity[1, "Hours"], Quantity[1, "Seconds"]}, {"Days", "Weeks", "Years"}] (but, say, Thread[f[{Quantity[1, "Hours"], Quantity[1, "Seconds"]}, {"Days",
"Weeks", "Years"}]] will give an error)

They do not have the attribute Listable because they are not truly listable. When built-in function have this attribute, it does not mean that they simply thread over the arguments in the same way you would do it with Map. It means that there is a separate, special evaluation procedure for evaluating them. I strongly suggest reading this answer from Leonid Shifrin.
QuantityMagnitude, on the other hand, is defined as:
QuantityMagnitude[Quantity[magnitude_, _]?QuantityQ] := magnitude;

QuantityMagnitude[list : _List|_?ArrayQ] := Map[QuantityMagnitude,list];

But it also has several other definitions for when it is applied to Association or TemporalData or Around ...

A good question.  I usually don't touch this sort of problem myself, but, my understanding is that it's not efficient. For example, it unpacks arrays.
array = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[array]
marray = QuantityMagnitude[array];
Developer`PackedArrayQ[marray]

Now try it out after SetAttributes[QuantityMagnitude, Listable]. The lists aren't packed.
Listable isn't really a description of a calling convention, but more of a directive on how to evaluate the function. And also, quantity stuff is also meant to work with QuantityArrays and I'm not sure we have a corresponding concept of an attribute for listability there?
I suppose that, ideally, you should be able to set something as Listable regardless of this fact and still have your own defined handling of list input. I'm not sure if that's difficult or just wasn't considered important.

I'm going to ask around a developer to at least fact check my answer.

Also, there's some behavior, with double list input where they might want different behavior than listability. I'm not sure off the top of my head what that might be.
